# jQuery Plugin Architecture Syntax - What does this line mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I was reading the jQuery documentation for plugin development and I ran across a line of code I cannot wrap my head around.

```
  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

if ( methods[method] ) {
  return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
} else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
  return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
} else {
  $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
}
```

The line in question:

```
return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));
```

I understand that all javascript objects inherit call() and apply() and I understand the differance between these two functions. What I don't understand is the prototype on the Array. Array objects already have a slice() so why is the prototype needed here? Since call() takes two arguments which are a 'this' (context) and a list of arguments I don't understand how the above call invocation works. Can someone help me understand this line?

Thanks

Comment: `arguments` is not an array (so has no `slice()` method of its own), but `slice()` will work on it if called this way (because it is an array-like object).

Comment: So then call() is being passed the second item(arguments[1]) in arguments?

Comment: `1` is actually the parameter for `slice()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arguments` object inherits from `Object.prototype`. It may look like an array, but it isn't. To perform array operations on it, the following line is necessary:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)
```

The previous line copies the `arguments` "array", and uses the `slice(1)` method on it.

`Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 1)` is equivalent to:

- Convert `arguments` to a true array (by setting `this` of Array.slice` to arguments)
- Use the `.slice(1)` method to return an array which does not contain the first element.

*(Note that the `arguments` object is not modified during this process)*

Pseudo-code:

```
var arguments = {1: "arg1", 2: "arg2", 3: "arg3", length: 3};
var copy = convert_object_to_array(arguments); //This function does not exists
// copy looks like: ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
copy.slice(1); //Returns ["arg2", "arg3"]
```

Comment: Totally makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very simply speaking, the function `Array.prototype.slice` is as follows:

```
Array.prototype.slice = function(from) {
    return elements of `this` from index `from`;
};
```

so when you do `Array.prototype.slice.call(obj, a)`, you'll get `obj` with elements only from index `a`.

The problem is that it is only available on arrays, but you can get it working on objects as well using the syntax you described:

```
var obj = { length: 3,   0: 'a',   1: 'b',   2: 'c' };
Array.prototype.slice.call(obj, 1); // { length: 2,   0: 'b',   1: 'c' }
```

The same goes for arguments - it isn't an array so you have to access the function with `Array.prototype.slice.call`.

Basically, the only thing that arrays are different from arguments is that arrays inherit from `Array.prototype`, so that you can can call `arr.slice()` directly.